# Looping through groups of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2014, I have a table with a number of rows for example 15, 5 have a groupid column of 736881 and 10 have a group id column 3084235.  What I want to do is process each group of records in turn and load the results in to a table.

I have written the code to do this but I think I am not setting the loopcounter incorrectly set as I keep getting the groupid of records 736881 loaded twice.

I cant't currently post the test data due to containing personal information but if  the mistake is not obvious I will try and create some dummy data.

```
SELECT @LoopCounter = min(rowfilter) , @maxrowfilter = max(rowfilter) 
FROM peops6

WHILE ( @LoopCounter IS NOT NULL
        AND  @LoopCounter <= @maxrowfilter)

begin

declare @customer_dist as Table (
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [First_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Last_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DoB] [date] NULL,
    [post_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [mobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](100) NULL );


INSERT INTO @customer_dist (id, First_Name, Last_Name, DoB, post_code, mobile, Email)
select id, first_name, last_name, dob, postcode, mobile_phone, email  from peops6 where rowfilter = @LoopCounter

insert into results
SELECT result.* ,
       [dbo].GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching(result.DoB, d.DoB) [DOB%match] ,
       [dbo].GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching(result.post_code, d.post_code) [post_code%match] ,
       [dbo].GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching(result.mobile, d.mobile) [mobile%match] ,
       [dbo].GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching(result.Email, d.Email) [email%match]
 FROM   (   SELECT (   SELECT MIN(id)
                      FROM   @customer_dist AS sq
                      WHERE  sq.First_Name = cd.First_Name
                             AND sq.Last_Name = cd.Last_Name
                             AND (   sq.DoB = cd.DoB  
                                     OR sq.mobile = cd.mobile
                                     OR sq.Email = cd.Email
                                     OR sq.post_code = cd.post_code )) nid ,
                  *
           FROM   @customer_dist AS cd ) AS result
       INNER JOIN @customer_dist d ON result.nid = d.id order by 1, 2 asc;

SELECT @LoopCounter  = min(rowfilter) FROM peops6
   WHERE rowfilter > @LoopCounter

end
```

Comment: It would help to see some sample data here.  Note that most of the time you don't need to use cursors in SQL, because most database operations already can do this.

Comment: " I have a table with a number of rows for example 15" - and the table is `peops6` in your example?

Comment: "... and load the results in to a table" - the table is `result` in your example?

Comment: That is correct Radim.  If the solution is not obvious I will try and create some dummy data.

Comment: At the end you recalculate the counter again from the peops6 table/view. But I don't see how anything changed in peops6. So why would that counter even change? Is `peops6` a view and the `results` table part of it?

Comment: Luk, I can see where you are coming from, I'm guessing I should be picking the next highest record from the peops6 table where the id is not already in the results table but I am not sure how to amend my code to take this in to account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to truncate your table variable (@customer_dist) at the end of the loop:

```
....
-- Add this
TRUNCATE TABLE @customer_dist

SELECT @LoopCounter  = min(rowfilter) FROM peops6
   WHERE rowfilter > @LoopCounter

end
```

See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/42ef20dc-7ad8-44f7-b676-a4596fc0d593/declaring-a-table-variable-inside-a-loop-does-not-delete-the-previous-data?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you need a LOOP like using a [SQL Cursor](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/cursor.aspx) to fulfill this task

Please check following SQL statement where I used multiple CTE expressions

```
with customer_dist as (
    select
        rowfilter,
        id, first_name, last_name, dob, postcode, mobile_phone, email
    from peops6 
), result as (
    SELECT
        (
        SELECT
            MIN(id)
        FROM customer_dist AS sq
        WHERE 
            sq.rowfilter  = cd.rowfilter
        AND sq.First_Name = cd.First_Name
        AND sq.Last_Name  = cd.Last_Name
        AND (sq.DoB = cd.DoB OR sq.mobile_phone = cd.mobile_phone OR sq.Email = cd.Email OR sq.postcode = cd.postcode )
        ) nid,
        *
    FROM customer_dist AS cd
)
SELECT 
    result.* ,
    [dbo].edit_distance(result.DoB, d.DoB) [DOB%match] ,
    [dbo].edit_distance(result.postcode, d.postcode) [post_code%match] ,
    [dbo].edit_distance(result.mobile_phone, d.mobile_phone) [mobile%match] ,
    [dbo].edit_distance(result.Email, d.Email) [email%match]
FROM result
INNER JOIN customer_dist d 
    ON result.nid = d.id 
order by 1, 2 asc;
```

Please note, I used my fuzzy string matching [Levenshtein Distance Algorithm](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/fuzzy-string-matching-using-levenshtein-distance-sql-server.aspx) in this sample instead of your function

And the outcome is as follows
[image]

Only you need to add the INSERT statement just before the last SELECT statement

Hope it is useful